# React.js Log all GraphQL queries in Sentry

Tags: reactjs, graphql, sentry, react-error-boundary

I have a **React** application which I've surrounded with an `ErrorBoundary` that sends errors to Sentry and it works fine. I would like to log all my GraphQL query errors into Sentry as well but my problem now is for all my GraphQL queries, I have a catch block where I dispatch an action for the failed query. 
When I remove the catch blocks, the errors are logged into Sentry but I'm unable to trigger the failed query action.

My solution now is to put `Sentry.captureException()` into each catch block of a GraphQL query which is very repetitive.

Is there a way to allow the `ErrorBoundary` to still catch GraphQL errors even if the query has it's own catch block?

```
function getEmployee() {
    return function(dispatch) {
        dispatch(requestEmployeeInformation());

        GraphqlClient.query({ query: EmployeeQuery, fetchPolicy: 'network-only' })
            .then((response) => {
                dispatch(receiveEmployeeInformation(response.data));
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                /* temporary solution. This sends error to sentry but is very repetitive because
                   it has to be added to every single action with a graphql query 
                 */
                Sentry.captureException(error)

                //dispatch this action if the query failed
                dispatch(failGetEmployee(error));
            });
    };
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can always throw the error again inside the catch block. However, the best way to handle this is by using [Error Link](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/v3.0-beta/api/link/apollo-link-error/). This will allow you to log both GraphQL errors (errors returned as part of the response) as well as network errors (failed requests, invalid queries, etc.).

```
import { onError } from '@apollo/client/link/error'

const link = onError(({ graphQLErrors, networkError, response }) => {
  if (graphQLErrors)
    graphQLErrors.map(({ message, locations, path }) =>
      Sentry.captureMessage(message)
    )
  if (networkError) {
      Sentry.captureException(networkError)
  }
  
  // Optionally, set response.errors to null to ignore the captured errors
  // at the component level. Omit this if you still want component-specific handling
  response.errors = null
});
```